# Which brokers offer a Python stock trading API?

Tags: programming, algorithmic-trading, python, broker, interactive-brokers

I would like to automate my trading strategies.

My strategies are not high-frequency and are written in Python.

I have a trading account in Interactive Brokers, and I know some non-official Python libraries (such as [ibPy](https://github.com/blampe/IbPy) and [swigPy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/swigibpy)) that are an interface to the Java API and are not officially supported.

Is there another broker that has a better stock trading API for Python?

Inspired by [Which brokers offer a .NET stock trading API?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/which-brokers-offer-a-net-stock-trading-api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no broker that provides an official, supported Python API. If you are at Interactive Brokers you can consider using their FIX gateway, but that comes with additional cost. [QuickFix](http://quickfixengine.org) provides a Python API.

Answer (score 3):

TradeStation offers python support via their WebAPI.  Check it out here: http://tradestation.github.io/webapi-docs/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com).  It's all in Python.  You can backtest and paper trade your algo for free.  We do live trading by hooking your algorithm to your Interactive Brokers account.